# Missing comet events on Tomcat 7 CometProcessor

Tags: java, tomcat, comet, long-polling, tomcat7

I am using CometProcessor to implement long-polling on Tomcat 7.0. The thing that bothering me is I don't get any other events except CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN.
The code sample:

```
    @Override
    public void event(CometEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = event.getHttpServletRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = event.getHttpServletResponse();
    if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
        LOGGER.info("Begin for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR) {
        LOGGER.error("Error for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        event.close();
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END) {
        LOGGER.info("End for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        event.close();
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.READ) {
        LOGGER.info("Read from session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
    }
```

I assume it could cause memory leaks because on the BEGIN event I store the response object in my local array.

Does any one have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is nothing to invoke the request end so it will just sit there until a timeout occurs.
In my experience, END is triggered when you call close, outside the context of the thread that calls begin.